# изображение на экране ноутбука-картинке

Tags: html

Как в html-вёрстке сделать изображение на экране ноутбука, если ноутбук и картинка на его экране являются разными изображениями?

Comment: А не проще в фотошопе соеденить и выложить сразу?

Comment: А так, посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312961/html-css-image-inside-image-how-to-do-that и много ответов гуглится на этот вопрос. Если у вас прям специфичная ситуация (повернуть под углом, перелистывать картинки на экране этого ноутбука, другое), уточните пожалуйста и добавте сюда код, который у вас получился.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать блок, где будет храниться изображение ноутбука. 
В нем с помощью позиционирования и подгонки размеров и margin-ов сделать "картинку"
Такое решение имеет место быть, если ваша картинка меняется на странице, возможно представляет собой слайдер, меняющееся в зависимости от каких-то событий изображение.

Если нет, то фотошопом просто прилепить картинку.